# Point of view in Eudora Welty's "A Worn Path"

Tags: short-stories, narrator, eudora-welty

In "[A Worn Path](https://archive.org/details/selectedstorieso0000welt/page/240/mode/2up)" by Eudora Welty, how can the story's point of view be described? How does the point of view affect what we know about the situation?

Comment: This looks like a homework question. That's not a problem *per se*, but asking us to *do your homework for you* certainly is. Please [edit] your post to focus on one key aspect (your question as it currently stands is too broad), add what ***you*** think the answer might be, and then explain what it is that you're unsure about. For further guidance, see [ask] and take our site's [Tour]. :-)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. People who have reviewed your question seem to think it is too broad, so I have removed the sub-question about suspense to make it a bit more focused. It would be OK to ask the question about suspense as a separate post.

Answer (score 1):

The point of view in ‘A Worn Path’ can be described as “[third-person, limited, objective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narration#Third-person)”. That is, it is told from the point of view of a “third person”, a narrator who not themselves a character in the story; it is “limited” (as opposed to “omniscient”), describing only things seen and experienced by the protagonist; and it is “objective” (as opposed to “subjective”) describing appearances and events, but not the protagonist’s thoughts.

The effect of “limited” narration is to give a strong impression of what it is like to see things from the perspective of the protagonist. For example, when she comes across a scarecrow, it is described like this:

> Then there was something tall, black, and skinny there, moving before her.
>
> A first she took it for a man. It could have been a man dancing in the field. But she stood still and listened, and it did not make a sound. It was silent as a ghost.
>
> “Ghost,” she said sharply, “who be you the ghost of? For I have heard of nary death close by.”

This conveys the threat to the protagonist inherent in the landscape—the figure of a man is dangerous to her—and her sense of the numinous, the possibility that she might meet the ghost of someone who recently died.

However, because the narration is objective, the reader gets no insight into what the protagonist is thinking or intending, except for what she says out loud or reveals through her actions and expressions. This allows Welty to preserve suspense as to why the protagonist is making this difficult and dangerous journey.